# Setting row category label location to the left in facetgrid & heat map seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like set a row category label location to the left. By default, the seaborn is setting to the right side of the graphs.

This post discusses a possible way to do it but I could not have it work it in my code.
[Python seaborn facetGrid: Is it possible to set row category label location to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134082/python-seaborn-facetgrid-is-it-possible-to-set-row-category-label-location-to-t)

Here is the example data and `facetgrid` and heatmap plot code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

print("seaborn version {}".format(sns.__version__))
# R expand.grid() function in Python
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131385/1135316
def expandgrid(*itrs):
   product = list(itertools.product(*itrs))
   return {'Var{}'.format(i+1):[x[i] for x in product] for i in range(len(itrs))}

methods=['method 1', 'method 2', 'method 3', 'method 4']
labels = ['label1','label2']
times = range(0,100,10)
data = pd.DataFrame(expandgrid(methods,labels, times, times))
data.columns = ['method','labels','dtsi','rtsi']
#data['nw_score'] = np.random.sample(data.shape[0])
data['nw_score'] = np.random.choice([0,1],data.shape[0])

labels_fill = {0:'red',1:'blue'}

def facet(data,color): #defining facet plot
    data = data.pivot(index="dtsi", columns='rtsi', values='nw_score')
    g = sns.heatmap(data, cmap=ListedColormap(['red', 'blue']), cbar=False,annot=True)

with sns.plotting_context(font_scale=5.5):
    g = sns.FacetGrid(data,row="labels", col="method", size=2, aspect=1, margin_titles=True)
    g = g.map_dataframe(facet)
    g.add_legend()
   # g.set(xlabel='common xlabel', ylabel='common ylabel')
    g.set_titles(col_template="{col_name}", fontweight='bold', fontsize=18)
```

which outputs this graph

[image]

So I add @John Karasinski's solution to my code but still not generating the plot that I want to see at the end of the post!

```
with sns.plotting_context(font_scale=5.5):
    g = sns.FacetGrid(data,row="labels", col="method", size=2, aspect=1,margin_titles=True)
    g = g.map_dataframe(facet)
    g.add_legend()
   # g.set(xlabel='common xlabel', ylabel='common ylabel')
    g.set_titles(col_template="{col_name}", fontweight='bold', fontsize=18)
    for i, axes_row in enumerate(g.axes):
        for j, axes_col in enumerate(axes_row):
            row, col = axes_col.get_title().split('|')

        if i == 0:
            axes_col.set_title(col.strip())
        else:
            axes_col.set_title('')

        if j == 0:
            ylabel = axes_col.get_ylabel()
            axes_col.set_ylabel(row.strip() + ' | ' + ylabel)
plt.show()
```

The graph I want to have is;

[image]

thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with sns.plotting_context(font_scale=5.5):
    g = sns.FacetGrid(data,row="labels", col="method", size=2, aspect=1, margin_titles=False)
    g = g.map_dataframe(facet)
    g.add_legend()
    g.set_titles(template='')

    for ax,m in zip(g.axes[0,:],methods):
        ax.set_title(m, fontweight='bold', fontsize=18)
    for ax,l in zip(g.axes[:,0],labels):
        ax.set_ylabel(l, fontweight='bold', fontsize=18, rotation=0, ha='right', va='center')

    plt.tight_layout() # automatically adjust spacing of axes
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Diziet, one point though I got an error saying `plt` is not defined!

Comment: sorry, add `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` to your import statements

Comment: alternatively, you can replace `plt.tight_layout()` with `g.fig.tight_layout()` if you don't want to import pyplot for no reason

Comment: is there anyway to get the methods on the bottom instead of the top?